# How to use Google API Sheets without OOB URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

My app is a ruby on rails one.
I developed in 2018 one which used OAuth 2.0 authentication with an OOB_URI. But this technique doesn't work anymore and the Google sheets API documentation had changed.

I don't really find my way anymore and don't really understand this new system. To be honest, I don't really know what type of OAuth identifier I should use. In my Google Cloud Console I created two profiles: a desktop and a web application.

With both profiles I get this error:

> "Error 400 : invalid_request
> The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Out-of-Band (OOB) flow migration guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.
> Query details: redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

My goal is to access data present in a Google Sheet (basically this is my source) and then play with it to create graphs, do calculations, etc. I must therefore have permanent access to Google Sheets and make a lot of calls.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"

  OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'.freeze
  APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
  CREDENTIALS_PATH = "config/google_sheets_credentials.json".freeze
  TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
  SCOPE = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::AUTH_SPREADSHEETS_READONLY 
  
  def authorize
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
    user_id = "default"
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
    if credentials.nil?
      url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
      puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " \
           "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
      code = gets
      credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
      )
    end
    credentials
  end

  def datasheets
    # Initialize the API
    service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    service.authorization = authorize

    # Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    # https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    spreadsheet_id = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"
    range = "Class Data!A2:E"
    response = service.get_spreadsheet_values spreadsheet_id, range
    puts "Name, Major:"
    puts "No data found." if response.values.empty?
    response.values.each do |row|
      # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
      puts "#{row[0]}, #{row[4]}"
    end
  end
```

In my gem file:

```
gem 'googleauth'
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'google-apis-sheets_v4'
```

Has anyone encountered this error before or tried to work around it?

Comment: Google has laid out a migration guide. There is really no away around except for following it.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but there is no documentation for ruby projects. Or maybe I mised it..